# .on("DOMNodeInserted", function(e){, e.currentTarget is always #document

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I'm in the process of updating a 2-year old application and part of that application has the following:

```
function setupListener(currentXmlHttpRequests){
  debugger;
  $(document).unbind("DOMNodeInserted");
  $(document).bind("DOMNodeInserted", function(e){
    debugger;
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
    if(e.target.id=="page-bottom"){
      refreshFilterList("Last 6 Months Of Launches");
      refreshQuickJump(filtered);
      $("#mySelect").on('change', function() {
        var val = this.value;
        if(val == "")
          return;
        document.getElementById(val).scrollIntoView();
        var element = document.getElementById('mySelect');
        element.value = "";

      });
      $("#datacenter").SumoSelect({placeholder: "All Datacenters"});
      $("#year").SumoSelect({placeholder: "All Years"});
      $("#platform").SumoSelect({placeholder: "All Platforms"});
      $("#tech").SumoSelect({placeholder: "No Technologies"});
      $("#tech")[0].sumo.selectItem(1);
      $("#tech")[0].sumo.selectItem(2);
      $("#tech")[0].sumo.selectItem(3);
      $("#version").SumoSelect({placeholder: "All Versions"});
      $("#query").keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
          setFilters();
          changeURL(scriptName);
          if(checkFiltersDefault())
            loadDefault();
          else
            filter(filteredServiceNames[env], true);
          refresh(currentXmlHttpRequests);
        }
      });
      $("#search").on("click", function(){
        setFilters();
        changeURL(scriptName);
        if(checkFiltersDefault())
          loadDefault();
        else
          filter(filteredServiceNames[env], true);
        refresh(currentXmlHttpRequests);
      });
      $("#clear").on("click", function(){
        clearFilters();
        changeURL(scriptName);
        loadDefault();
        refresh(currentXmlHttpRequests);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

But when this is entered, `e.currentTarget` is always `#document` and `e.target.id` is always blank. This results in the listeners never being applied.

`page-bottom` is setup in another method before this one:

```
function setupLast(dashboard) {
    dashboard.rows.push({
        title: 'Chart',
        height: 25,
        editable: false,
        panels: [{
            title: ' ',
            type: 'text',
            span: 0,
            mode: 'html',
            content: "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div id=\"page-bottom\"  style=clear:both></div></body></html>",
            height: 25,
            transparent: true,
            id: -1
        }]
    });
}
```

The guy who wrote this originally inserted this div as a way for us to watch for when the page has finished loading. His old docs have:

> Most dashboards have an invisible panel that is added at the end of
>   the dashboard for the purpose of knowing when it is safe to  perform
>   jquery event binding, among other things. This works by using jquery's
>   'DOMNodeInsert' event to wait for the div inside the panel to be added
>   to the page.

I'm not exactly sure what the issue is - if maybe when the base application was upgraded (2 years worth of upgrades) it upgraded the jquery version, or if I'm just missing something. I can see that `page-bottom` does actually end up in the page. When the page loads though, these listener setups never get executed.

Comment: Just FYI `DOMNodeInserted` is rather outdated. Try using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead

Answer (score 1):

I would just do away with that `div` detection mechanism and use the jQuery api method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  refreshFilterList("Last 6 Months Of Launches");
  refreshQuickJump(filtered);
  $("#mySelect").on('change', function() {
    var val = this.value;
    if(val == "")
      return;
    document.getElementById(val).scrollIntoView();
    var element = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    element.value = "";

  });
  $("#datacenter").SumoSelect({placeholder: "All Datacenters"});
  $("#year").SumoSelect({placeholder: "All Years"});
  $("#platform").SumoSelect({placeholder: "All Platforms"});
  $("#tech").SumoSelect({placeholder: "No Technologies"});
  $("#tech")[0].sumo.selectItem(1);
  $("#tech")[0].sumo.selectItem(2);
  $("#tech")[0].sumo.selectItem(3);
  $("#version").SumoSelect({placeholder: "All Versions"});
  $("#query").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
      setFilters();
      changeURL(scriptName);
      if(checkFiltersDefault())
        loadDefault();
      else
        filter(filteredServiceNames[env], true);
      refresh(currentXmlHttpRequests);
    }
  });
  $("#search").on("click", function(){
    setFilters();
    changeURL(scriptName);
    if(checkFiltersDefault())
      loadDefault();
    else
      filter(filteredServiceNames[env], true);
    refresh(currentXmlHttpRequests);
  });
  $("#clear").on("click", function(){
    clearFilters();
    changeURL(scriptName);
    loadDefault();
    refresh(currentXmlHttpRequests);
  });
});
```

Comment: unfortunately `ready` appears to fire too early - the page doesn't finish loading before trying to attach listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `e.target` instead of `currentTarget`